# Гласные и согласные

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика, терминология

Читая учебник испанского языка, заметил названия типа *Гласные **буквы** и звуки*. Но ведь только звуки могут быть гласными или согласными, а буквы — значки.

Можно ли, на ваш взгляд, употреблять словосочетания наподобие *согласных букв*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В разговорном, а отчасти и в научном, стиле - вполне. Под сочетаниями *гласные (согласные) буквы* понимают буквы для обозначения соответствующих звуков.

Такое обозначение имеет некоторый смысл, например букву Й для надобностей старой русской орфографии частенько относили к полугласным, в отношении собственно звуков такое обозначение не применялось. Нечто подобное имеет место и в отношении английских полугласных **букв** Y и W.