# Почему названия звуков употребляются в среднем роде?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика, терминология

Вроде бы всё понятно: звук — значит, мужской род. Но отчего мы говорим иногда *«О безударн**ое**»*, к примеру? То же самое можно нередко наблюдать в авторитетных учебниках, справочниках, на сайтах. Этому есть объяснение или просто так сложилось? Откуда взялся средний род?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первоначально автор спрашивал, как правильно: *И краткое* или *И краткий*. В данном случае речь идет о названиях букв, а не звуков, поэтому правильно говорить *И краткое*. Тогда почему средний род, а не женский? Вот что говорит [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=224915):

*Названия большинства букв русского алфавита - существительные среднего рода. Так указано в "Словаре русского языка" в 4 т. под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. Ср.: и краткое (й), э оборотное (э).*

Что касается выражений типа "о безударное", то и здесь речь идет о буквах. Это не вполне корректно, но так принято: говоря о буквах, подразумевают буквы для обозначения соответствующих звуков (см. ответ @behemothus на вопрос [Гласные и согласные](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426497/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)).

Comment: Вот те раз! А я сколько раз слышала что-то наподобие: «Здесь беглая/выпадающая Е» или «Здесь должна стоять А вместо О». И привыкла считать, что названия букв имеют тот же род, что и родовое слово — простите мне тавтологию... Да, а название буквы по-любому пишется прописной? Ведь пишут: *О безударное*, а не ***о безударное***? Тем не менее, встречаются и **Э оборотное**, и **э оборотное**.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, мы говорим буквы А, О. Буква — это приложение, родовое название, а вот сама буква (А, О) относится к среднему роду, что видно при согласовании с прилагательным: **заглавное А, безударное О.**

Для сравнения: **заглавная буква А, безударная буква О.** В этом случае прилагательное относится к родовому слову буква, а оно ж. р.

Безударное О — это буква, обозначающая гласный звук **в безударной позиции.**

**И краткое** (И с краткой) [Как называется дужка в букве «й»? | Ответы Mail.Ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/12463941)

**Кра́тка** (ранее кра́ткая; также бре́вис, дужка) — один из кириллических надстрочных чашеобразных диакритических знаков; заимствована из древнегреческой письменности, где означала краткость гласных. На славянской почве стала обозначать неслоговой их характер. Регулярно используется с XV—XVI вв., преимущественно над буквой И.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему названия звуков употребляются в среднем роде?

И не только "звуков". Вообще, все у чего или для чего род неизвестен, неопределен или не важен, тяготеет к среднему роду. "Оно", "это" "нечто" - все среднего рода.  Для звуков (не для букв!) обычно вопрос о том, какого они грамматического рода, отходит на второй план. Отсюда и эта форма среднего рода.

> Вроде бы всё понятно: звук — значит, мужской род.

У филологов - да. Они, как правило, в курсе, что "А" или "Б" - это звуки, да еще часто противопоставляемые буквам, поэтому филологи следуют этому правилу. Но простые  смертные не особо и задумываются, что речь идет о звуке, а не просто о неком самодостаточном понятии, и родовое слово не имеет такого императивного влияния на грамматический род самого понятия.